# PSQL lo_import in client side script

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

we have a simple sql script we maintain that sets up your schema and populates a set of text/example values - so it's just like create table, create table table insert into table... and we run it with a simple shell script which calls psql

one of our tables requires files - what I wanted to do was just have the files in the same directory as the script and do something like insert into repository (id, picture) values ('first', lo_import('first.jpg'))

but I get errors saying must be superuser to use server-side script.  Is there any way I can achieve this?   I have just a .sql file and a bunch of image files and by running psql against the file import them?

Running as superuser is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `psql`, you could write a shell script like

```sh
oid=`psql -At -c "\lo_import 'first.jpg'" | tail -1 | cut -d " " -f 2`
psql -Aqt -c "INSERT INTO repository (id, picture) values ('first', $oid)"
```

Answer (score 1):

because comments can't have code - thanks to Laurenz, I got it "working" like this:

```
drop table if exists some_landing_table;
create table some_landing_table( load_time timestamp, filename varchar, data bytea);

\set the_file 'example.jpg';
\lo_import 'example.jpg';
insert into some_landing_table
    select now(), 'example.jpg', string_agg(data,decode('','escape') order by pageno)
    from 
        pg_largeobject 
    where 
        loid = (select max(loid) from pg_largeobject);

select lo_unlink( max(loid) )   from pg_largeobject;
```

however, that is ugly for two reasons -

- I don't seem to be able to get the result of \lo_import into a variable in any way.    even though `select \lo_import filename` works `select \lo_import filename into x` doesn't.
- I can't use a variable - if I do `\lo_import :the_file` - it just says example.jpg doesn't exist - enven though if I put it in directly it works perfectly
- I can't find a simpler way of providing a 0 length bytea field than `decode('','escape')`